# Como puedo hacer un Card de 2 columnas

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, responsive

Quisiera saber como se podría hacer esto tanto en css puro con html y en bootstrap con html y que sea **Responsive** por favor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar y colocar los 2 tipos de código que necesito, gracias!

Este es el codigo que intente hacer pero me sale la imagen arriba y la info abajo.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card class="col-3"">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="img.jpg" alt="alternative">
              </div>
            <div class="card class="col-3"">
                <h3>Hola</h3>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card class="col-3"">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="img.jpg" alt="alternative">
              </div>
            <div class="card class="col-3"">
                <h3>Hola</h3>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: ¿Y tú que has intentado?

Comment: Ya deje el ejemplo abajo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para anidar columnas en Bootstrap hay que poner una fila (.row) contenedora de las mismas:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card col-6">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="img.jpg" alt="alternative">
      </div>
      <div class="card col-6">
        <h3>Hola</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card col-6">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="img.jpg" alt="alternative">
      </div>
      <div class="card col-6">
        <h3>Hola</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Si me ah funcionado, eres grande!